# Flutter pass variable to FloatingActionButton

Tags: flutter, dart, parameter-passing

I have an app where I have a bluetooth connection to a colorimeter.

I have a button to make a measurement, but somehow I am not able to get a specific variable into the onPressed function. The variable is passed to the main page (I have multiple tabs) via a callback, and then I want to somehow access the variable from the onPressed function.

I do not need to modify it. I have the feeling that this should be very simple to do, but somehow I have literally no idea on how to do it.

Here is my main.dart, hopefully with all the necessary information (the variable I was talking about is the `BluetoothConnection myConnection` variable).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'Results.dart';
import 'Measurement.dart';
import 'Standards.dart';
import 'Preferences.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bluetooth_serial/flutter_bluetooth_serial.dart';

class HeaderContainer {
  static ResultHeader resultHeader;
  static StandardHeader standardHeader;

  HeaderContainer();

  static void updateHeader() {
    resultHeader = ResultHeader();
    standardHeader = StandardHeader();
  }
}

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  HeaderContainer.updateHeader();
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: MyTabs(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyTabs extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyTabsState createState() => _MyTabsState();
}

class _MyTabsState extends State<MyTabs> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController controller;
  BluetoothConnection myConnection;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = TabController(
      vsync: this,
      length: 4,
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('ColorSuite'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.amber[800],
        bottom: TabBar(
          tabs: <Tab>[
            Tab(
              child: Text('Messung'),
            ),
            Tab(
              child: Text('Verlauf'),
            ),
            Tab(
              child: Text('Standards'),
            ),
            Tab(
              child: Text('Einstellungen'),
            ),
          ],
          controller: controller,
          isScrollable: true,
        ),
      ),
      body: new TabBarView(
        controller: controller,
        children: [
          Meas(),
          ResultList(),
          StandardList(),
          Prefs(parentAction: (BluetoothConnection connection) {
            setState(() {
              myConnection = connection;
            });
          }),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(


        onPressed: () {

          if(connection != null && connection.isConnected){
            //proceed further
          }
          else{
            //do something else
          }
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        backgroundColor: Colors.amber[800],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you should use myConnection in FloatingActionButton.

Comment: oh, yes. I told you it is probably dead simple, but that i was that stupid i never could have imagined

Comment: no worries, it happens sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think instead of connection you should use myConnection

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(

    onPressed: () {

      if(myConnection!= null && myConnection.isConnected){
        //proceed further
      }
      else{
        //do something else
      }
    },
    child: Icon(Icons.add),
    backgroundColor: Colors.amber[800],
  ),
);
```

Comment: yes, connection was just a placeholder for what I was gonna use. Sorry if it caused confusion.